# Intervalo na execução do PHP

Tags: php

Tenho feito um código em PHP que executa 3 querys, a cada query exibe uma mensagem, gostaria de saber como dar um intervalo de 800ms após a mensagem para executar a próxima query, por exemplo:

```
<?php
$sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `user_id` = '1';";
$query_1 = mysqli_query( $conexao, $sql_1 );
$count_1 = mysqli_num_rows( $query_1 );
echo $count_1 . "<br>\n";

// INTERVALO DE 800ms

$sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM `tbl2` WHERE `user_id` = '1';";
$query_2 = mysqli_query( $conexao, $sql_2 );
$count_2 = mysqli_num_rows( $query_2 );
echo $count_2 . "<br>\n";

// INTERVALO DE 800ms

$sql_3 = "SELECT * FROM `tbl3` WHERE `user_id` = '1';";
$query_3 = mysqli_query( $conexao, $sql_3 );
$count_3 = mysqli_num_rows( $query_3 );
echo $count_3 . "<br>\n";

// INTERVALO DE 800ms

header('Location: page/user/');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sleep.php - Atrasa a execução do programa por um dado número de seconds.

Comment: Em geral isso é errado de se fazer, e este parece ser o caso, parece que precisa de outra solução, mas não temos como saber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `sleep()` do `PHP`. Ela recebe como parâmetro a quantidade de segundos. Mas aconselho você pesquisar uma forma de implementar `Queues` na sua aplicação.

```
$sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `user_id` = '1';";
$query_1 = mysqli_query( $conexao, $sql_1 );
$count_1 = mysqli_num_rows( $query_1 );
echo $count_1 . "<br>\n";

// INTERVALO DE 800ms
sleep( 0.8 );

$sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM `tbl2` WHERE `user_id` = '1';";
$query_2 = mysqli_query( $conexao, $sql_2 );
$count_2 = mysqli_num_rows( $query_2 );
echo $count_2 . "<br>\n";

// INTERVALO DE 800ms
sleep( 0.8 );

$sql_3 = "SELECT * FROM `tbl3` WHERE `user_id` = '1';";
$query_3 = mysqli_query( $conexao, $sql_3 );
$count_3 = mysqli_num_rows( $query_3 );
echo $count_3 . "<br>\n";

// INTERVALO DE 800ms
sleep( 0.8 );

header('Location: page/user/');
exit();
```

Comment: Bem comentado Kayo, uso de queues, boa. Obrigado pela ajuda e atenção prestada.